# should you index a many-to-many table?

Tags: sql-server

should you index a many to many table such as user_role where it has 2 fields (userId and RoleId) ?

and what kind of index would be best?

Comment: You would typically have a composite primary key on these tables so really the only question is to make it `userId,RoleId` vice-versa or have both.

Comment: @Martin: whats the fastest way to add these indexes? i have a bunch of these many-2_many tables to update...

Comment: I would look at the usage first to see if any other indexes are necessary. Unless you already know which ones will get heavy traffic. See the link in my answer for more info.  :-P

Comment: @rich: This is a new DB that once goes to production will be virtually unchangeable.

Comment: Ok. Then you will just have to do your best to estimate which tables will be hit hard and/or have a lot of data. Don't go index-crazy though, because too many indexes _will_ slow things down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. If there are a lot of user/role combinations (tens of thousands or more), and you are querying this information a lot, or need it to be particularly performant, then yes.

If there are not very many records, or you don't care if it's very performant, or don't use it very often, then most likely no.

For the usage part, SQL Server can help you decide if this is used enough to warrant an index. See [here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/optimizing_indexes_general_p1.aspx) for some guidance.

Also, as Martin pointed out, if you have defined user/role as a primary key on this table, you already have an index, the clustered index, for that combination of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes will help query a table faster, it really has nothing to do with the relationship itself. Are you queries slow? If so, then adding an index would help that. It will add some overhead to the insert and update statements.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, if you join on a field it's a good idea to have an index on it.

Your mileage may vary depending on table size, selectivity of the field (i.e. how many distinct values it has) and your ratio of updates/inserts to selects/seeks.